# Any techniques or tricks to modifying existing functions in C++?

Tags: c++, signals-slots, qt-signals

Within JavaScript, you can pull off something like this:

```
function bunny() { alert("The bunny jumped."); }

var oldBunny = bunny;
function bunny() {
  oldBunny();
  alert("The bunny also ran.");
}

bunny(); // The bunny Jumped. The bunny also ran.
```

As one can see, the old "bunny" function had code appended to it by copying to a variable, then recreating the function with the same name. The copy of the original function runs, and the new code also runs.

I wish to replicate a similar mechanic in C++.

Now before you have a meltdown and start explaining the differences between static and dynamic languages, I get it. I'm not looking for something identical to what's provided, but I do desire something similar.

Furthermore, I'm not trying to do this to modify existing code; I wish to format my own source code to allow such a mechanic for other users to take advantage of.

One of the first ideas I had was to perhaps setup various macros within the code that could later be modified by other files.

Another idea would be to create a Signal and Slots system like in QT. Though I have no clue how to do such a thing myself.

Thank you for reading; I hope you have some suggestions.

Comment: In C++ it's not really possible. For things like that one typically uses *inheritance*.

Comment: Can't you use method overriding technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you recognize which feature of JavaScript functions makes this possible, it's not too hard to do the same in C++. In JavaScript functions also have closures, which regular function in C++ don't have. But C++ lambdas are of a closure type. And if one defines `bunny` to be something which can both hold an object of a closure type, and be reassigned, you're all set.

The C++ standard library offers a nice default choice for this, in the form of `std::function`. We can just re-write your original JavaScript as follows:

```
std::function<void()> bunny = [] {
  std::cout << "The bunny jumped.\n";
};

auto oldBunny = std::move(bunny);
bunny = [oldBunny] {
  oldBunny();
  std::cout << "The bunny also ran.\n";
};

bunny();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use functors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string operator ()()
    {
        return "Base call";
    }

    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::string operator()()
    {
        return "Wrapper: " + Base::operator()();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* pFun = new Base;
    std::cout << "Now check Base: " << (*pFun)() << std::endl;

    delete pFun;
    pFun = new Derived;
    std::cout << "Now check Derived: " << (*pFun)() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you show is less about functors and more about *inheritance* and *`virtual` function overriding*.

Comment: Good solution, but you should really use `std::unique_ptr` to manage the heap-allocated objects. It would prevent the memory leak you have now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the goal is to allow the calling code to extend the program's functionality beyond what the initial code provided, I might use a user-updatable array of functor-objects, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Function
{
public:
   virtual void Call() = 0;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Function> FunctionSharedPointer;

class OldBunny : public Function
{
public:
   virtual void Call()
   {
      std::cout << "The bunny jumped." << std::endl;
   }
};

class NewBunny : public Function
{
public:
   NewBunny(FunctionSharedPointer oldFunction) : _oldFunction(oldFunction) {/* empty */}

   virtual void Call()
   {
      _oldFunction->Call();
      std::cout << "The bunny also ran." << std::endl;
   }

private:
   FunctionSharedPointer _oldFunction;
};

enum {
   FUNCTION_BUNNY,
   // other functions could be declared here later...
   NUM_FUNCTIONS
};

// Our table of functions that the user can Call() if he wants to
static FunctionSharedPointer _functionTable[NUM_FUNCTIONS];

// Wrapper function, just to keep users from accessing our table directly,
// in case we ever want to change it to something else
void CallFunction(int whichFunction)
{
   _functionTable[whichFunction]->Call();
}

// Another wrapper function
void SetFunction(int whichFunction, FunctionSharedPointer newFunctionDefinition)
{
   _functionTable[whichFunction] = newFunctionDefinition;
}

// And another
FunctionSharedPointer GetFunction(int whichFunction)
{
   return _functionTable[whichFunction];
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   // Our default function values get set here
   SetFunction(FUNCTION_BUNNY, std::make_shared<OldBunny>());

   std::cout << "before:" << std::endl;
   CallFunction(FUNCTION_BUNNY);

   // Now let's update an entry in our function table to do something different!
   FunctionSharedPointer op = GetFunction(FUNCTION_BUNNY);
   FunctionSharedPointer np = std::make_shared<NewBunny>(op);
   SetFunction(FUNCTION_BUNNY, np);

   std::cout << "after:" << std::endl;
   CallFunction(FUNCTION_BUNNY);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void bunny()
{
    cout << "The bunny jumped." << endl;
}

void oldBunny()
{
    bunny();
}

void newBunny()
{
    bunny();
    cout << "The bunny also ran." << endl;
}

#define bunny newBunny

int main()
{
    bunny();
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't need `oldBunny()`, just remove it.

Comment: Using macros that way is just mean, and will make the code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: It's one way to do what you claimed impossible.